# Allocating array doesn't increase struct size

Tags: arrays, c

I have a struct containing an array of int (int[]) which I allocate dynamically. But when I check the size with sizeof() I don't find any increased (array) size. Printed results is shown far below.

What am I doing wrong?

```
typedef struct
{
    int TE_I;
    int TV_I;
    int TV_J;
    int CrossPointTV;
    int EdgeOrder;
    int OtherNakedFaceEdge;
    bool Visited;
    int *CrossPointConnectedEdges[1]; // ptr to dynamic int[] array
} mesh_edge_index_info;
```

```
int main()
    int edges_cnt = 10;
    mesh_edge_index_info *p_edge = malloc(1 * sizeof(*p_edge));;

    printf("size of edge in bytes        : %d\n", sizeof(*p_edge));
    printf("size of edge.TE_I            : %d\n", sizeof(p_edge->TE_I));
    printf("size of edge.TV_I            : %d\n", sizeof(p_edge->TV_I));
    printf("size of edge.TV_J            : %d\n", sizeof(p_edge->TV_J));
    printf("size of edge.CrossPointTV    : %d\n", sizeof(p_edge->CrossPointTV));
    printf("size of edge.EdgeOrder       : %d\n", sizeof(p_edge->EdgeOrder));
    printf("size of edge.OtherNFceEdge   : %d\n", sizeof(p_edge->OtherNakedFaceEdge));
    printf("size of edge.Visited         : %d\n", sizeof(p_edge->Visited));
    printf("size of edge.CrossPtConnEdges: %d\n", sizeof(p_edge->CrossPointConnectedEdges));


    printf("\n   Address of edge                  = %u", &p_edge);
    printf("\n   Address of edge.TE_I             = %u", &p_edge->TE_I);
    printf("\n   Address of edge.TV_I             = %u", &p_edge->TV_I);
    printf("\n   Address of edge.TV_J             = %u", &p_edge->TV_J);
    printf("\n   Address of edge.CrossPointTV     = %u", &p_edge->CrossPointTV);
    printf("\n   Address of edge.EdgeOrder        = %u", &p_edge->EdgeOrder);
    printf("\n   Address of edge.OtherNFcEdge     = %u", &p_edge->OtherNakedFaceEdge);
    printf("\n   Address of edge.Visited          = %u", &p_edge->Visited);
    printf("\n   Address of edge.CrossPtConnEdges = %u", &p_edge->CrossPointConnectedEdges);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("-- add int[10] --");
    printf("\n\n");

    p_edge->CrossPointConnectedEdges = malloc(edges_cnt * sizeof(*p_edge->CrossPointConnectedEdges));

    //int ConnectedEdges[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    for (int i = 0; i < edges_cnt; i++)
    {
        p_edge->CrossPointConnectedEdges[i] = i;
    }

    printf("size of edge in bytes        : %d\n", sizeof(*p_edge));
    printf("size of edge.CrossPtConnEdges: %d\n", sizeof(p_edge->CrossPointConnectedEdges));

    return 0;
```

**Printed result** -- The two last rows should (in my expectations) have increased in size to `sizeof(int) * 10` but I see no change, so I must be doing something wrong:

```
    ================================================    
    size of edge in bytes        : 40
    size of edge.TE_I            : 4
    size of edge.TV_I            : 4
    size of edge.TV_J            : 4
    size of edge.CrossPointTV    : 4
    size of edge.EdgeOrder       : 4
    size of edge.OtherNFceEdge   : 4
    size of edge.Visited         : 4
    size of edge.CrossPtConnEdges: 8
    
       Address of edge                  = 676329832
       Address of edge.TE_I             = 3576450480
       Address of edge.TV_I             = 3576450484
       Address of edge.TV_J             = 3576450488
       Address of edge.CrossPointTV     = 3576450492
       Address of edge.EdgeOrder        = 3576450496
       Address of edge.OtherNFcEdge     = 3576450500
       Address of edge.Visited          = 3576450504
       Address of edge.CrossPtConnEdges = 3576450512
    
    // Add int[10]
    
    size of edge in bytes        : 40   // <-- no increase !
    size of edge.CrossPtConnEdges: 8    // <-- no increase !
    ================================================
```

Comment: Except for VLAs, `sizeof` is a compile time operator.  It can't give you the value runtime variables (such as `edges_cnt`) much less deduce that a pointer variable is being used to store a malloc-allocated pointer and figure out the size of the memory addressed by it.

Comment: `int *CrossPointConnectedEdges[1]; // ptr to dynamic int[] array` this comment is incorrect, `[1]` means an array of size 1 exactly. Trying to access out of bounds of the array causes undefined behaviour (even if there happens to be allocated memory )

Comment: Sorry for not responding quicker, I had to unplug everything due to a thunderstorm passing by. 
@M.M, I understand your point, but after (re)allocating this member is actually doing what the comment says (with no access violations). The problem I had was with the sizes.... However, the suggestions in this thread has much nicer and cleaner solutions. Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field *CrossPointConnectedEdges* of record *mesh_edge_index_info*, as you have declared it, is not a pointer to an array, but a one-element array of pointer to integer. What you want is simply a pointer to integer:

```
int *CrossPointConnectedEdges;
```

Memory allocation in C is quite low-level and error prone so it is easier to define an allocation macro and use that instead of the malloc function. Also it makes more sense to store the length of the array in the record so they are kept together. Here is how I would do it:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NEW_ARRAY(ptr, n) \
        { \
                (ptr) = malloc((size_t) (n) * sizeof (ptr)[0]); \
                if ((ptr) == NULL) { \
                        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failed: %s\n", strerror(errno)); \
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
                } \
        }

#define NEW(ptr) NEW_ARRAY(ptr, 1)

typedef struct {
    int TE_I;
    int TV_I;
    int TV_J;
    int CrossPointTV;
    int EdgeOrder;
    int OtherNakedFaceEdge;
    int Visited;
    int edgesCount;
    int *CrossPointConnectedEdges;
} mesh_edge_index_info;


int main(void)
{
    mesh_edge_index_info *p_edge;
    int i;

    NEW(p_edge);
    p_edge->edgesCount = 10;
    NEW_ARRAY(p_edge->CrossPointConnectedEdges, p_edge->edgesCount);
    for (i = 0; i < p_edge->edgesCount; i++) {
        p_edge->CrossPointConnectedEdges[i] = i;
    }

    /*...*/

    free(p_edge->CrossPointConnectedEdges);
    free(p_edge);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really like your macro solution. Nice and clean. Now that the thunderstorm passed by (one hour drive north of Stockholm) I will evaluate the two solutions provided (so far) in the thread. I learn from both of them. Many thanks!

Comment: Macro alternative : drop the cast  `(size_t)`.  It quiets warnings that should not get quieted.  When `n` is signed, either the calling code should use some unsigned type or this macro should detect negative values.  Else macro hides bugs.

Comment: Two questions: #1. Is any of the two alternative solutions involving C++ or is it "pure" C99? (I'm new to C and for the moment I'd like to avoid dragging in any C++ stuff in the current project.)
#2. I will - apart from the internal int array - also create an array of the `mesh_edge_index_info` struct, typically with a size of 2k up to 4k elements (naked edges). This means that I will have a dynamic array of `mesh_edge_index_info` structs which in turn contains the discussed dynamic member array. Will that mess up the memory allocation due to different internal member array sizes?

Comment: @RIL The code in my example is even pure ANSI C89 (i.e. no C++ involved). I cannot see why your proposed approach would not work.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` will give you **only the size of the pointer** not the size of the allocated memory. BTW there is no way in "plain: to get this information. You need to store it somewhere in your struct.

`int *CrossPointConnectedEdges[1]; // ptr to dynamic int[] array`

it is not pointer to the dynamic int[] array. It is a one element array of `int *` pointers.

I would do it another way:

```
typedef struct
{
    int TE_I;
    int TV_I;
    int TV_J;
    int CrossPointTV;
    int EdgeOrder;
    int OtherNakedFaceEdge;
    bool Visited;
    size_t numberofEdges;
    int CrossPointConnectedEdges[];
} mesh_edge_index_info;


mesh_edge_index_info *allocate(mesh_edge_index_info *eis, size_t nEdges, bool zero)
{
    eis = realloc(eis, sizeof(*eis) + nEdges * sizeof(eis -> CrossPointConnectedEdges[0]));
    if(eis) 
    {
        if(zero) memset(eis, 0, sizeof(*eis) + nEdges * sizeof(eis -> CrossPointConnectedEdges[0]));
        eis -> numberofEdges = nEdges;
    }
    return eis;
}

int main(void)
{
    //allocate new with 100 edges and zero the struct.
    mesh_edge_index_info *eis = allocate(NULL, 100, true);

    //change the number (too 500) ofthe edges keeping the vsalues
    eis = allocate(eis, 500, false);
}
```

Comment: I think saying it's a compile-time operator would be better than **sizeof will give you only the size of the pointer not the size of the allocated memory** may be?

Comment: @Lucas It is, but it will simply give `sizeof(int)` (given a `int *p_edge;`) and the corresponding `printf` format specifier should be `%zu`, not `%d`.

Comment: @SaiSreenivas it does not matter if it is compile time or run time, the important is what it will give. BTW `sizeof`

Comment: in the OP question sizeof(*p_edge) will give size of the struct in bytes

Comment: @P__J__ Right ! Then it should be: `sizeof(*p_edge) == sizeof(struct mesh_edge_index_info);` but previously you were sayin `== sizeof(int)`?

Comment: @P__J__, thank you for a very nice solution. Beautiful code, I'll have to pick one of two very attractive solutions... so bear with me. Regarding the "<code>not pointer to the dynamic int[] array</code>"-thing, it actually is, after reallocation, running without access violations, but yes, a clean `int *ptr` is how it's done -- if the struct (including the dynamic array) is safe to access before I know the number of array elements (it's not known at the time I need to create the struct). It seems you covered the initial case with the "zero" option. I'll try that. Looks good. Cheers!

Comment: @RIL everything is safe here. You can first allocate with zero elements then with as many as you wish.